# t-foreach="docs" only takes 80 records, I need all records

Tags: odoo-10

When I select all records, in a tree search:

```
t-foreach="docs" t-as="o"
```

It only takes 80 records, but I need to include the rest. ¿How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the number of record to show on the tree view but i don't recommend to do so:

[image: Change limit of tree view]

Or use Wizard to search and print the result of search and this is the best solution.

because in more menu the ids that passed to action are those who are selected by the user

Comment: I don't have that dropdown, are you sure it's available on all modules? Do I have to install a specific Addon?

Comment: @Jonathan yes it's available in the tree view all you have to do is click on the number that shows how many record are shown per pages. Then this drop down will appear if it didn't may be you are not using an new version of you navigator

Comment: I see it now, I had to click for it to appear